# get late employee from database using entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I am working in web app and I have 2 table 1 employees, 2-log_time(emp_id:int , log_time :datetime ,log_type : string ) i use calendar to select date and i wont Retrieve employee that log_lime=calunder.selectedday and log time>8 am .

2-retrive late employee between two selected date ,

any idea

Comment: Got any problematic code or you're asking the SO community to write it for you? What have you tried that's not working?

Comment: thank u for  interesting I try many of ways but I can get it .I have a datetime and I wont to use part of day(2013-05-11) to check the day and part of time (08:20:12) to chick time >in fact I don't now how to do this .if you tell me the we I will be grateful.

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, NHibernate or any other ORM or you're just sending plain SQL to the database? Help us help you and it will be a pleasure to give an answer. Your question does not provide enough information, please consider editing your post so we can help you better. Also consider posting some code and reading through the SO FAQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT Employees.Emp_id,Employees.First_Name,Employees.Manager_Id,Log_Time.Log_Time FROM Log_Time join Employees on(Employees.Emp_id=Log_Time.Emp_Id) WHERE (convert (date,Log_Time) BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}') and convert(time,Log_Time.Log_Time)>='08:00:00'

this is worked